# Jquery Vert Scroller - only moves body,html - not #div?

Tags: jquery

http://subzerostudio.com/temp/verticalscroller/temp.html

I want this scroll to effect the div#container instead of the body,html

but if I change

```
$("body,html").animate({
```

to

```
$("#container").animate({
```

it breaks..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only scroll on scrollpanes. As long as `#container`'s overflow is not set to scroll, it just won't do anything. If you want to scroll the browser's viewport to the element `#container`, you should indeed animate the scrolling on the `html` element.

Comment: so how would I achieve a simple animated vertical scroll to div effect with a fixed nav at the top, I've tried cycle and googled a bunch of unhelpful tuts - surely it need not be more than a couple lines of jquery?!

Comment: As you seem to have tried before: `$("html").animate({scrollTop: $("#container").offset().top}, 2000)`. The fixed navigation should not interfere with this in any way.